# Logistic regression returns error but runs okay on reduced dataset

Tags: r, statistics, regression, glm, logistic-regression

I would appreciate your input on this a lot!

I am working on a logistic regression, but it is not working for some reason:

```
mod1<-glm(survive~reLDM2+yr+yr2+reLDM2:yr +reLDM2:yr2+NestAge0,
         family=binomial(link=logexp(NSSH1$exposure)),
                       data=NSSH1, control = list(maxit = 50))
```

When I run the same model with less data it works! 
But with the complete dataset I get an error and warning messages:

```
Error: inner loop 1; cannot correct step size
In addition: Warning messages:
1: step size truncated due to divergence 
2: step size truncated due to divergence
```

This is the data: https://www.dropbox.com/s/8ib8m1fh176556h/NSSH1.csv?dl=0

Log exposure link function from [User-defined link function for glmer for known-fate survival modeling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19012128/user-defined-link-function-for-glmer-for-known-fate-survival-modeling):

```
library(MASS)
logexp <- function(exposure = 1) {
    linkfun <- function(mu) qlogis(mu^(1/exposure))
    ## FIXME: is there some trick we can play here to allow
    ##   evaluation in the context of the 'data' argument?
    linkinv <- function(eta)  plogis(eta)^exposure
    mu.eta <- function(eta) exposure * plogis(eta)^(exposure-1) *
      .Call(stats:::C_logit_mu_eta, eta, PACKAGE = "stats")
    valideta <- function(eta) TRUE
    link <- paste("logexp(", deparse(substitute(exposure)), ")",
               sep="")
    structure(list(linkfun = linkfun, linkinv = linkinv,
               mu.eta = mu.eta, valideta = valideta, 
               name = link),
          class = "link-glm")
}
```

Comment: it's better to include code in-line whenever possible.  Also note that the linked question has an updated link function of this type ...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**tl;dr** you're getting in trouble because your `yr` and `yr2` predictors (presumably year and year-squared) are combining with an unusual link function to cause numerical trouble; you can get past this using the [glm2 package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/glm2/index.html), but I would give at least a bit of thought to whether it makes sense to try to fit the squared year term in this case.

**Update**: brute-force approach with `mle2` started below; haven't yet written it to do the full model with interactions.

Andrew Gelman's [folk theorem](http://andrewgelman.com/2008/05/13/the_folk_theore/) probably applies here:

> When you have computational problems, often there’s a problem with your model.

I started by trying a simplified version of your model, without the interactions ...

```
NSSH1 <- read.csv("NSSH1.csv")
source("logexpfun.R")  ## for logexp link
mod1 <- glm(survive~reLDM2+yr+yr2+NestAge0,
          family=binomial(link=logexp(NSSH1$exposure)),
          data=NSSH1, control = list(maxit = 50))
```

... which works fine. Now let's try to see where the trouble is:

```
mod2 <- update(mod1,.~.+reLDM2:yr)  ## OK
mod3 <- update(mod1,.~.+reLDM2:yr2) ## OK
mod4 <- update(mod1,.~.+reLDM2:yr2+reLDM2:yr)  ## bad
```

OK, so we're having trouble including both interactions at once.  How are these predictors actually related to each other? Let's see ...

```
pairs(NSSH1[,c("reLDM2","yr","yr2")],gap=0)
```

[image]

<s>`yr` and `yr2` aren't *perfectly* correlated, but they're perfectly rank-correlated and it's certainly not surprising that they're interfering with each other numerically</s> *Update: of course "year" and "year-squared" look like this! even using `poly(yr,2)`, which constructs an orthogonal polynomial, doesn't help in this case ... still, it's worth looking at the parameters in case it provides a clue ...*

As mentioned above, we can try `glm2` (a drop-in replacement for `glm` with a more robust algorithm) and see what happens ...

```
library(glm2)
mod5 <- glm2(survive~reLDM2+yr+yr2+reLDM2:yr +reLDM2:yr2+NestAge0,
          family=binomial(link=logexp(NSSH1$exposure)),
          data=NSSH1, control = list(maxit = 50))
```

Now we do get an answer. If we check `cov2cor(vcov(mod5))`, we see that the `yr` and `yr2` parameters (and the parameters for their interaction with `reLDM2` are strongly negatively correlated (about -0.97). Let's visualize that ...

```
library(corrplot)
corrplot(cov2cor(vcov(mod5)),method="ellipse")
```

[image]

What if we try to do this by brute force?

```
library(bbmle)
link <- logexp(NSSH1$exposure)
fit <- mle2(survive~dbinom(prob=link$linkinv(eta),size=1),
     parameters=list(eta~reLDM2+yr+yr2+NestAge0),
     start=list(eta=0),
     data=NSSH1,
     method="Nelder-Mead")  ## more robust than default BFGS
summary(fit)
##                   Estimate Std. Error  z value   Pr(z)    
## eta.(Intercept)  4.3627816  0.0402640 108.3545 < 2e-16 ***
## eta.reLDM2      -0.0019682  0.0011738  -1.6767 0.09359 .  
## eta.yr          -6.0852108  0.2068159 -29.4233 < 2e-16 ***
## eta.yr2          5.7332780  0.1950289  29.3971 < 2e-16 ***
## eta.NestAge0     0.0612248  0.0051272  11.9411 < 2e-16 ***
```

This seems reasonable (you should check predicted values and see that they make sense ...), but ...

```
cc <- confint(fit)  ## "profiling has found a better solution"
```

This returns an `mle2` object, but one with a mangled call slot, so it's ugly to print the results.

```
coef(cc)
## eta.(Intercept)                      eta.reLDM2 
##     4.329824508                    -0.011996582 
##       eta.yr                         eta.yr2 
##     0.101221970                     0.093377127 
##     eta.NestAge0 
##      0.003460453 
##
vcov(cc) ## all NA values! problem?
```

Try restarting from those returned values ...

```
fit2 <- update(fit,start=list(eta=unname(coef(cc))))
coef(summary(fit2))
##                     Estimate  Std. Error    z value        Pr(z)
## eta.(Intercept)  4.452345889 0.033864818 131.474082 0.000000e+00
## eta.reLDM2      -0.013246977 0.001076194 -12.309102 8.091828e-35
## eta.yr           0.103013607 0.094643420   1.088439 2.764013e-01
## eta.yr2          0.109709373 0.098109924   1.118229 2.634692e-01
## eta.NestAge0    -0.006428657 0.004519983  -1.422274 1.549466e-01
```

Now we can get confidence intervals ...

```
ci2 <- confint(fit2)
##                       2.5 %       97.5 %
## eta.(Intercept)  4.38644052  4.519116156
## eta.reLDM2      -0.01531437 -0.011092655
## eta.yr          -0.08477933  0.286279919
## eta.yr2         -0.08041548  0.304251382
## eta.NestAge0    -0.01522353  0.002496006
```

This seems to work, but I would be **very** suspicious of these fits.  You should probably try other optimizers to make sure you can get back to the same results.  Some better optimization tool such as AD Model Builder or Template Model Builder might be a good idea.

I don't hold with *mindlessly* dropping predictors  with strongly correlated parameter estimates, but this might be a reasonable time to consider it.

Comment: I get an error with your glm call: `Error in glm.fit(x = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,  : 
  NAs in d(mu)/d(eta)` with R 3.3.0 on Mac El Cap.

Comment: The first `glm` call? I can believe that this is all sufficiently sensitive that it will crap out at different points on different platforms. Does `glm` work if you drop `yr2` from the formula? Does `glm2` work for you?

Comment: glm2 also fails with or without yr2. Same error message.

Comment: huh. in that case I would probably go with brute-force MLE if I *needed* to do this. Maybe I'll wait to hear back from the OP whether it worked for them.  Also possible that a cloglog link (quite similar to the power-logistic) would work better.

Comment: Thanks for your answers @Ben Bolker and 42, yes I get an error message with the new link function and `glm2` package. Using `yr` and `yr2` as a continuous variable (i.e. `1,2,3` and `1^2, 2^2, 3^2` either) get the same error (in the data I shared with you it was standardized with the function scale, none of them work). The aim of the analysis is to look for changes over time on the season (which is non-linear because of predation and it is the reason to include yr and relative laying date (reLDM) interaction as squared terms). Could you potentially help me to implement this `MLE` approach?

Comment: Thanks a lot @Ben Bolker, I tried the solution with two interactions and it gives me estimates (including a weird intercept) but not std errors or p-values. I agree with you there is something wrong with my model and I should drop this predictor. However, the reason to have it is because the nesting success - laying date (reLDM) relationship for every year is non-linear and we want to look for systematic changes over time in this relationship. I know this is not a biology forum ^^ but maybe you can tell me if this a good idea. The full model with reLDM works perfect but not with reLDM2.