# PCA: How does princomp() work and can I use it to pick up variables for ARIMA?

Tags: r, machine-learning, time-series, pca, forecasting

I'm trying to use PCA to pick good predictors to use in the `xreg` argument of an `arima` model to try to forecast the `tVar` variable below. I am just using the reduced dataset below with just a few variables to make the example simple.

I am trying to understand how the formula argument in `princomp` works. For the `pc` object below, is it saying "use `xVar1` and `xVar2` to explain the variance in `na.omit(dfData[,c("tVar","xVar1","xVar2")])`" ?

What I ultimately would like to do is create a new variable which explains most of the variance in `tVar`. Is that something I can do using PCA?  If so, could someone please explain how or point me towards an example?

Code:

```
pc <- princomp(~xVar1+xVar2,
               data = na.omit(dfData[,c("tVar","xVar1","xVar2")]), 
               cor=TRUE)
```

Data:

```
dput(na.omit(dfData[1:100,c("tVar","xVar1","xVar2")]))
structure(list(tVar = c(11, 14, 17, 5, 5, 5.5, 8, 5.5, 
          6.5, 8.5, 4, 5, 9, 10, 11, 7, 6, 7, 7, 5, 6, 9, 9, 6.5, 9, 3.5, 
          2, 15, 2.5, 17, 5, 5.5, 7, 6, 3.5, 6, 9.5, 5, 7, 4, 5, 4, 9.5, 
          3.5, 5, 4, 4, 9, 4.5, 6, 10, 9.5, 15, 9, 5.5, 7.5, 12, 17.5, 
          19, 7, 14, 17, 3.5, 6, 15, 11, 10.5, 11, 13, 9.5, 9, 7, 4, 6, 
          15, 5, 18, 5, 6, 19, 19, 6, 7, 7.5, 7.5, 7, 6.5, 9, 10, 5.5, 
          5, 7.5, 5, 4, 10, 7, 5, 12), xVar1 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
          0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
          0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
          0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
          0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
          1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
          0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L),
          xVar2  = c(0L, 
          1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
          2L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
          0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
          0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 2L,
          0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
          1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
          0L)), .Names = c("tVar", "xVar1", "xVar2"
          ), row.names = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 
          13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L,25L, 
          26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 37L,38L, 
          39L, 40L, 41L, 42L, 43L, 44L, 45L, 46L, 47L, 48L, 49L, 50L,51L, 
          52L, 54L, 55L, 56L, 57L, 58L, 59L, 60L, 61L, 62L, 63L, 64L, 65L,
          66L, 67L, 68L, 69L, 70L, 71L, 72L, 73L, 74L, 75L, 76L, 77L, 78L, 
          79L, 80L, 81L, 82L, 83L, 84L, 85L, 86L, 87L, 88L, 89L, 90L, 91L, 
          92L, 93L, 94L, 95L, 96L, 97L, 98L, 99L, 100L),
          class  = "data.frame", na.action = structure(c(8L,53L),
          .Names = c("8", "53"), class = "omit"))
```

Comment: You can definitely do that using PCA. Explaining how to do it is going to be like writing a chapter on it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

*(This is a very good post! It is interesting to have another post today regarding PCA. Though that question is more basic, regarding [the difference between `princomp` and `prcomp`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37349662/4891738), but the mathematical details with R code I make in [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37350344/4891738) may be beneficial to any one learning PCA.)*

PCA is used for dimension reduction (low-rank approximation), when:

1. you have a lot of (say `p`) correlated variables `x1, x2, ..., xp`;
2. you want to shrink them to a small number (say `k < p`) of new, linearly independent variables `z1, z2, ..., zk`;
3. you want to use `z1, z2, ..., zk` rather than `x1, x2, ..., xp` to predict a response variable `y`.

---

**A fundamental picture and a little mathematics**

Suppose you have a response variable `y`, a full linear regression without dropping any variables should take the formula:

```
y ~ x1 + x2 + ... + xp
```

However, we can do a reasonable **approximate** model, after PCA. Let `X` be the model matrix in above, i.e., the matrix by combining all observations of `x1, x2, ... , xp` by column, then

```
S <- cor(X)  ## get correlation matrix S
E <- eigen(S)  ## compute eigen decomposition of S
root_eigen_value <- sqrt(E$values)  ## square root of eigen values
eigen_vector_mat <- E$vectors  ## matrix of eigen vectors
X1 <- scale(X) %*% eigen_vector_mat  ## transform original matrix
```

Now, `root_eigen_value` (a length-`p` vector) is monotonically decreasing, i.e., the contribution to total covariance is decreasing, hence we can only select the first `k` values. Accordingly, we can select the first `k` columns of transformed matrix `X1`. Let's do:

```
Z <- X1[, 1:k]
```

Now, we have successfully reduced `p` variables to `k` variables, and each column of `Z` is the new variable `z1, z2, ..., zk`. Bear in mind that these variables are not a subset of original variables; they are completely new, without names. But since we are only interested in predicting `y`, it does not matter what name we give to `z1, z2, ..., zk`. Then we can fit an approximate linear model:

```
y ~ z1 + z2 + ... + zk
```

---

**Use `princomp()`**

In fact, things are easier, because `princomp()` does all the computation for us. By calling:

```
pc <- princomp(~ x1 + x2 + ... + xp, data, cor = TRUE)
```

we can get all we want. Among the a few returned values in `pc`:

1. `pc$sdev` gives `root_eigen_value`. If you do `plot(pc)`, you can see a barplot showing this. If your input data are highly correlated, then you are expected to see a near exponential decay in this figure, with only a few variables dominating the covariance. (*Unfortunately, your toy data is not going to work. `xVar1` and `xVar2` are binary, and they are already linearly independent, hence after PCA, you will see that they both give equal contribution.*)
2. `pc$loadings` gives `eigen_vector_mat`;
3. `pc$scores` gives `X1`.

---

**Use `arima()`**

The variable selection process is simple. If you decide to take the first `k` variables out of a total of `p` variables, by inspecting `plot(pc)`, then you extract the first `k` columns of the `pc$scores` matrix. Each column forms `z1, z2, ..., zk`, and pass them to `arima()` via argument `reg`.

---

**Back to your question about formula**

> For the pc object below, is it saying "use xVar1 and xVar2 to explain the variance in na.omit(dfData[,c("tVar","xVar1","xVar2")])"

After my explanation, you should know the answer is "No". Do not mix response variable `tVar` used in the regression step, with the predictor variables `xVar1`, `xVars`, ... used in the PCA step.

`princomp()` allows three ways to pass in arguments:

1. by formula and data;
2. by model matrix;
3. by covariance matrix.

You have chosen the first way. The formula is used to tell `princomp()` to extract data from `data`, and it will later compute model matrix, covariance matrix, correlation matrix, eigen decomposition, till we finally get the result of PCA.

---

**Follow-up on your comments**

> So if I understand correctly, PCA is primarily for reducing the number of variables, and I shouldn't include the response variable `tVar` in the formula **or data**. But I was wondering why `princomp(~xVar1+xVar2, data = na.omit(dfData[,c("tVar","xVar1","xVar2")]), cor=TRUE)` and `princomp(na.omit(dfData[,c("xVar1","xVar2")]), cor=TRUE)` are basically equivalent?

The formula tells how to extract matrix from the data frame. Since you use the same formula `~ xVar1 + xVar2`, whether you include `tVars` in the data frame to pass to princomp makes no difference, as that column will not be touched by `princomp`.

Do not include `tVars` in your formula for PCA. As I said, regression and PCA are different problems, and shall not be confused with each other.

> To be clear, the strategy with PCA isn't to create a new variable which is a combination of `xVar1` and `xVar2` and explains most the variance in `tVar`, but rather to create a new variable which is a combination of `xVar1` and `xVar2` and explains most the variance of `dfData[,c("xVar1","xVar2")]`?

Yes. Regression (or `arima()` in your setting) is used to set up relation between your response `tVars` and predictor variables `x1, x2, ..., xp` or `z1, z2, ..., zk`. A regression/arima model will explain the mean and variance of response, in terms of predictors.

PCA is a different problem. It only select a low rank (fewer parameters) representation of your original predictor variables `xVar1, xVar2, ...`, so that you can use fewer variables in later regression / ARIMA modelling.

Still, you might need to think about whether you should do PCA for your problem.

1. Do you have a lot of variables, say 10+? In statistical modelling, it is common to reach hundreds of thousands of parameters. Computation can get very slow if we use all of them. PCA is useful in this case, to reduce computational complexity, while giving a reasonable representation of original covariance.
2. Are your variables highly correlated? If they are readily linearly independent of each other, PCA may not drop anything. For example, the toy data `xVar1` and `xVar2` you gave are just linearly independent, so dimension reduction is impossible. You can view the correlation in your data, by `pairs(mydata)`. A better visualization may be to use `corrplot` R package. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37336010/4891738) for examples on how to use it to plot covariance matrix.

Comment: Thank you for the excellent answer!  So if I understand correctly PCA is primarily for reducing the number of variables, and I shouldn't include the response variable tVar in the formula or data.  Also I was wondering are princomp(~xVar1+xVar2,
               data = na.omit(dfData[,c("tVar","xVar1","xVar2")]), 
               cor=TRUE)    and   princomp(na.omit(dfData[,c("xVar1","xVar2")]), 
               cor=TRUE)  basically equivalent?

Comment: To be clear, the strategy with PCA isn't to create a new variable which is a combination of xVar1 and xVar2 and explains most the variance in tVar, but rather to create a new variable which is a combination of xVar1 and xVar2 and explains most the variance dfData[,c("xVar1","xVar2")]?

Comment: Right, PCA doesn't consider your response variable at all in choosing components, just variation within data. If that variation corresponds to variation in the response, you are golden -- but if not, you might be led to discard a dimension needed to explain the response. Look into Partial Least Squares as a way to do "supervised" dimension reduction that takes the response variable into account.