# User-defined random intercept distribution for glmer

Tags: r, lme4

In glmer, random effects are normally distributed.  My research involves non-gaussian random effects distributions.  Is there a way to specify a non-gaussian random effects distribution for glmer?  I know there can be [user-defined links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19012128/user-defined-link-function-for-glmer-for-known-fate-survival-modeling) -- I'm hoping there's some similar option for random effects distributions. If not, I'd appreciate insights for how to edit/contribute to [lme4 source code](https://github.com/lme4/lme4) to allow for non-gaussian random intercept distributions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you want is basically impossible; the machinery of `lme4` very strongly depends on a Gaussian distribution (on the link/linear-predictor scale) of the conditional modes.

If I wanted to fit models with non-Gaussian distributions of random effects I would use a Bayesian-toolbox approach (JAGS or Stan, or PyMC ...).  Richard McElreath's [rethinking](https://github.com/rmcelreath/rethinking) package might offer a *relatively* painless front-end for constructing appropriate Stan models ... For example, the code below assumes a t-distributed rather than a Gaussian random effect and "works" (i.e. runs without errors - I will warn you that it could still be a lot of work to get this to do reliable estimation)

```
## devtools::install_github("rmcelreath/rethinking")
## also need to install rstan ...
library(lme4)
library(rethinking)

f2 <- alist(
    Reaction ~ dnorm( mu , sigma ),
    mu <- b0 + b0j[Subject] + b1*Days,
    b0j[Subject] ~ dstudent(df, 0 , sigma_group ),
    b0 ~ dnorm( 0 , 10 ),
    b1 ~ dnorm( 0 , 10 ),
    sigma ~ dlnorm( 0 , 1 ),
    sigma_group ~ dlnorm( 0 , 1 ),
    df ~ dlnorm(5,1)
)

m1 <- map2stan(f2, data=sleepstudy, verbose=TRUE)
```

Some algorithms have been designed for mixed modeling with non-Gaussian random effects in a more traditional frequentist, optimization-based framework (e.g., [Google scholar search on "non-Gaussian random effects"](https://scholar.google.ca/scholar?q=%22non-Gaussian+random+effects%22)), but I'm not aware of any of them having been implemented in R.